# CMake: Errors finding headers in a GLFW project

Tags: opengl, makefile, cmake, glfw

I got problems with CMake working with GLFW (OpenGL).

my CMakeList.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(test)

set(SRC Test.cpp)
add_executable(test ${SRC})

find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)
find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories( ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
include_directories( ${GLEW_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
include_directories( ${GLFW_INLUDE_DIRS} )

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glew32 ${GLEW_LIBRARIES} )
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} glfw3 ${GLFW_LIBRARIES} )
```

I don't get any errors while running this CMake-script but when I run make I always get this error:

```
fatal error: <GLFW/glfw3.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

I tried everything, but I don't know why it doesn't find this file.

Answer (score 0):

You can get make to show you more output.

So I suggest that you execute

```
make VERBOSE=1
```

and see what -I flags are being used as arguments to your compiler.

Also I noticed that

```
pkg_search_module(SOMETHING ..)
```

is being used like this by others:

```
pkg_search_module(SOMETHING ..)
if (SOMETHING_FOUND)
    include_directories(${SOMETHING_INCLUDE_DIRS})
else (SOMETHING_FOUND)
    PkgError_Later("Could not find SOMETHING (pkg name: lib-dev)")
endif (SOMETHING_FOUND)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hints! Now I added this lines into my CMakeLists.txt file:`find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_search_module(GLFW REQUIRED glfw3)
if (GLFW_FOUND)` cmake still doesn't complain but I still get the same error while running make.
    include_directories( ${GLFW_INLUDE_DIRS} )
else (GLFW_FOUND)
    message("Could not find GLFW (pkg name: lib-dev)")
endif (GLFW_FOUND)

Answer (score 0):

First you should correct the typo *GLFW_INLUDE_DIRS* on line:

```
include_directories(${GLFW_INLUDE_DIRS})
```

If that does not solve your problem, here is a minimal CMakeLists.txt that works for me. It does not use `PkgConfig`.

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)                                          
 project(GLFW-hello-world)                                                    

 find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)                                                
 include_directories(${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})                                   

 if(DEFINED ENV{GLFW_INSTALL_DIR})                                            
     find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED PATHS $ENV{GLFW_INSTALL_DIR})            
     get_filename_component(GLFW_BASE $ENV{GLFW_INSTALL_DIR} ABSOLUTE)        
     include_directories("${GLFW_BASE}/include")                              
 else()                                                                       
     message("GLFW_INSTALL_DIR not set, searching in default location(s)")    
     find_package(glfw3 3.2 REQUIRED)                                         
 endif(DEFINED ENV{GLFW_INSTALL_DIR})                                         

 add_executable(main main.c)                                                  
 target_link_libraries(main ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})                              
 target_link_libraries(main glfw)
```

Where main.c is the example code on [this page](http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html), and GLFW was compiled with shared libraries (`-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON`)

The first branch of the `if` is for the case where GLFW was compiled and installed locally (the environnement variable `GLFW_INSTALL_DIR` should be set to the install dir), the second is for the case where GLFW was installed to the default location (I did test only the first case).